# Cascading microservices using Meteor

Tags: meteor, package, cluster-computing, microservices

I've been looking into scaling Meteor, and had an idea by using the [Meteor Cluster package](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3z66g-7XLAhWDRhQKHS_qBwsQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmeteorhacks%2Fcluster&usg=AFQjCNEy9N5lo-9TmjFYvjgmCCO93mAwmg);

- Create a super-service*, which the user connects to, containing general core packages to be used by every micro-service (api, app, salesSite, etc. would make use of its package),
- The super-service then routes to the appropriate micro-service (e.g., the app), providing it with the functionality of its own packages.

(* - as in super- and sub-, not that it's awesome... I mean it is but...)

The idea being that I can cascade each service as a superset of the super-service. This would also allow me to cleverly inherit functionality for other services in a cascading service style. E.g.,

unauthedApp > guestApp > userApp > modApp > adminApp,

for the application, where the functionality of the previous service are inherited to the preceding service (e.g., the further right along that chain, the more extra functionality is added and inherited).

Is this possible?

EDIT: If possible, is there a provided example of how to implement such a pattern using micro-services?

**[[[[[ BIG EDIT #2: ]]]]]**

Think I'm trying to make a solution fit the problem, so let me re-explain so this question can be answered based on the issue rather than the solution I'm trying to implement.

Basically, I want to "inherit" (for lack of a better word) the packages depended on needed functionality, so that no code is unnecessarily sent through the wire.

So starting with the core packages, which has libraries I want all of my services to have, I then want to further "add" the functionality as needed. Then I want to add page packages if serving a page-based service (instead of, say, the API service, which doesn't render pages), then the appropriate role-based page packages, etc., until the most specific packages are added.

My thought was that I could make the services chain in such a way that I could traverse through from the most generic to most specific service, and that would finally end with a composition of packages from multiple services. So, for e.g., the guestApp, that might be the core packages + generic page packages + generic app packages + unauthApp packages + guestApp packages, so no unneccessary packages are added.

Also with this imaginary pattern I'm describing, I don't need to add all my core packages to each microservice - I can deal with them all within the core package right at the top of the package traversal I've discussed above and not have to worry about forgetting to add the packages to the "inherited" packages.

Hope my reasoning here makes sense, and I hope you guys know of a best practice for doing this. Thank you!

Comment: The cluster package seems to be inactive now

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock :( seems you're right looking at the issues log. Do you happen to know any other packages for a microservice architecture on Meteor?

Comment: It still works fine for a lot of people

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy Can you be more specific? Do you happen to know what problems are people having with the cluster?

Comment: I have not referred to any problems, but they are listed here: https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster/issues Yet, lots of people are using cluster "without problems"so you should definitely give it a try before dismissing it.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. I also use it in production without issue. I wanted to write a fuller response before. There are some issues that don't look like getting fixed any time soon

Comment: “First Experiences Scaling A Meteor App” https://medium.com/@eliezer/first-experiences-scaling-a-meteor-app-14a48e62a4af

Comment: That's an article of my own experiences with this stuff. Cluster was my first option for scaling, but I ended up going with nginx mostly

Comment: Lovely article! Thank you for your help Eliezer

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock I've revised my question, I'd love for you to take a look at it and see if it was just my ignorance about driving a solution rather than the problem I'm solving. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Hm, this big edit sounds like a code organization problem rather than an app "segregation" problem. You can go with the official "package" structure or use meteor 1.3 and make use of module imports. Have a base repository of private packages/modules and each separate app could "import" necessary packages/modules at "build time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
Yes! That's a good use to a microservice architecture.

Long answer:
Microservices don't necessarily provide you an inheritence mechanism as in OOP. You should consider microservices as independent "functions" which take in an input and respond with an output/action. Any microservice can depend on another to complete its own task.

And then, you "compose" necessary microservices in order to achieve the final output/action.

You can have one or few web facing "frontend" services that use a mix of few other backend microservices whose ports are not open to the public network.

The drawback with a microservice would be its "minimum footprint". The idea with microservices is around some main benefits:

- Separate core services so that they can be "maintained" independently
- Separate core services so that they can be "replaced" independently
- Separate core services so that they can be "scaled" independently

But then, each microservice, being a node/meteor app, will have its minimum cpu/ram footprint even when they are just idle and waiting for a connection.

Furthermore, managing a single monolithic app, or just a few "largish" services is much easier, from a devops standpoint, than managing tens of individual deployments.

So with all engineering decisions, the right answer would imply some kind of "balance".

Edit: reference to inheritence

As per the OP's comment, the microservices can indeed be referenced from a parent code as either functions or classes and be composed (functions) or inherited from (classes) because after all the underlying functionality are DDP endpoints.

If you are using the cluster package from meteorhacks

```
// create a connection to your microservice
var someService = Cluster.discoverConnection("someService");
// call a normal meteor method from that service
var resultFromSomeService = someService.call("someMethodFromSomeService");
```

So as with any piece of javascript code, you can wrap the above piece of code in a function or a [class with its constructor and all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and inherit from it, exposing its interfaces as you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think it really solves the question. I understand why microservices are useful, as well as their DevOps limitations (I will happily blow the guy who makes scaling anything easy). What I'm asking is if it is possible to implement the type of OOP-style cascading that I've described in the question. If so,how could I implement such a pattern?

Comment: Thanks, this looks right. I will take a look into this and mark it as the answer once I've tried it out!

Comment: I highly suggest a functional approach with composition instead of an object oriented approach with inheritance.

Comment: I agree I'm doing it wrong - please see the editted question for a bette explanation of thew problem I'm trying to solve, rather than the solution I'm trying to crowbar

Comment: sorry, forgot to tag you!